# Repeated and rotated text watermark on the whole document

Tags: watermark

I need to fill the page (100%) with the watermark text repeated and rotated under 45 degrees. I should to do it for every page in document.
This code works good, but in this case I have only one watermark at center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand{\filename}{/home/Documents/c.pdf}
\newcommand{\watermark}{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]  \node [black,opacity=0.1,rotate=45,scale=4.0] at (current page.north west)  {This is watermark text to repeat again and again} -- (current page.south east);}

\begin{document}
\foreach \index in {1,...,\the\pdflastximagepages}
{
\includepdf[pages=\index,pagecommand={\watermark}]{\filename}
}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: You can try to use `\foreach \pos in {...}` to set the node on path `(current page.north west) -- node[pos=\pos, ...] {...} -- (current page.south east)` and use the trick in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219478/how-to-include-multiple-pdf-pages-using-foreach-as-tikzpicture

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck thanks. I have updated source code in question. But still getting only one line of watermark.

Comment: You mean you want to cover the page with lots of copies from your text?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, exactly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand*\watermarktext[1]{\leavevmode\hbox to 2\textwidth{\leaders\vbox to 2\textheight{\leaders\hbox{#1}\vfil}\hfil}}


\newcommand{\watermark}{\tikz[remember picture, overlay]  
 \node [black,opacity=0.1,rotate=45,scale=4.0] at (current page.center)  
   {\watermarktext{This is watermark text to repeat again and again}};}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\watermark}]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thank you so much!