# Watermark loads a little bit later in Adobe Reader

Tags: watermark

I'm covering pdf pages with [watermark using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547690/repeated-and-rotated-text-watermark-on-the-whole-document). Everything works great. But the issue is that only Adobe Reader loads watermark a little bit later than pdf content. Less than half seconds, but enough to catch content without watermark using print screen or video recording. Is it possible to render them simultaneously?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Maybe this is interesting for you instead of accelerating the loading process of the watermark: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24210/is-there-a-package-to-secure-rendered-pdf-with-a-password

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect the content in your PDF with a watermark, this is not going to work sufficiently secure. The reason is, that each object in the PDF can still be accessed separately, it is just a matter of the tool used.

With Inkscape or Adobe Acrobat you can easily load a PDF and remove content and then see what is behind without the watermark.

So maybe describe what you finally want to achieve and I can modify this answer on the go.

Comment: Thank you. Pages must be filled with watermark in the background. It's not supposed to be a security feature, but we just want the document to load smoothly.

Comment: Ok, if it is about quality, please post a MWE and report the type and filesize of your watermark.

Comment: here it is my latex file: https://pastebin.com/A5a4R1EB
Works great. But Adobe Reader renders watermark later than pdf content (there is no such problem in xreader and web browsers).