# Include pdfpages and unwanted scale

Tags: pdfpages, include

When I include a pdf file with the command `\includepdf[pages=1]{file}` from the package `\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}`, I obtain a scaled document (in a smaller height). How can I obtain rigorously the same pdf file in input and output file ?

I give the original file (Picture number one, where the coloured blue and yellow bars are on all the page) and the file obtained (number 2, the bad scaled one)

## Picture 1

[image]

## Picture 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably needs the `noautoscale=true` and/or `fitpaper=true` options to the `\includepdf` command. Section 2.2 of [pdfpages documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf), or [Including a PDF page in LaTeX with pdfpages without scaling](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19383/including-a-pdf-page-in-latex-with-pdfpages-without-scaling).

Comment: @MikeRenfro I tried these options found in the doc but the problem remains... I'll see the question "Including a PDF...

Comment: With the file Sweave.sty of the discussion on the page http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19383/including-a-pdf-page-in-latex-with-pdfpages-without-scaling I obtained the third image scaled (and translated) on the width now..

Comment: Now trying with the package Sweave and the option fitpaper=true for includepdf, the output seems good... but I don't understand the reason of all this disturbance.. I'll be gratefull if one can indicate a document explaining this. Thks